# Disable driver signature enforcement on AWS (Amazon) server | Windows 2012

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, drivers

I need to disable driver signature enforcement on a Windows 2012 that is running on Amazon AWS.
So there is no way for me to get to the server on the restart screen to choose that feature on the server starting phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in elevated `cmd` and then reboot:

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS 
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

Note that extra `D` in `DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS` is not a typo.

More information:

- [Enable the Intel 82579V NIC in Windows Server 2012](http://www.ivobeerens.nl/2012/08/08/enable-the-intel-82579v-nic-in-windows-server-2012/)
- [HOWTO: Create a Boot Configuration That Has No Driver Signature Checks. Disable Driver Integrity Checks and Install a Custom Non-Signed Driver](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/903c2088-4fe1-440e-8a98-5fe34d0980e4/howto-create-a-boot-configuration-that-has-no-driver-signature-checks-disable-driver-integrity?forum=w8itprogeneral)

> I've tried that but it still won't work, the server is restarting in
>   "Test Mode"

Looks like [support for DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS was removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10358491/4424236).

> when I try to install the driver (Ghostscript PDF) the wizard tell me
>   its unsigned when I press next ofter giving the printer a name it
>   won't go to the next step...

There is alternate ways to get unsigned driver installed. Given that you already have your Windows in `Test Mode` you can [sign Ghostscript driver yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585322/4424236) or just grab [already signed binaries](https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/signed-ghostscript-pdf-printer-driver) from [here](http://dl.unicontsoft.com/upload/ghostpdf_signed.zip)

More information:

- [Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider 1.3b](http://www.ngohq.com/?page=dseo) (Gui tool to test-sign files)

If everything fails, you can also try [ReadyDriver Plus](http://uhlik.sk/?page=swreadydriver) ([tutorial](http://forums.citadelindustries.net/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=4)) , but it will be hard to debug if it fails, because you don't have access to boot menu.

> ReadyDriver Plus install itself as boot.bin file, and then modifies
>   Windows Vista Boot Configuration Data (BCD), which is then read by
>   Windows Boot Manager (the bootloader for Vista) to load ReadyDriver.
>   When Windows Vista boot loader reads BCD, it loads ReadyDriver which
>   will then makes the appropriate selection to disable Signed Driver
>   Signature Enforcement, based on what user choose to install. So in a
>   way, ReadyDriver Plus manages to permanently disable driver signing
>   enforcement in Windows Vista, both x32 and x64, by automatically
>   select “Disable Driver Signature Enforcement” option in the “Advanced
>   Boot Options” menu on system startup.

Comment: Great! I'm checking your suggestion

Comment: I've tried that but it still won't work, the server is restarting in "Test Mode", when I try to install the driver (Ghostscript PDF) the wizard tell me its unsigned when I press next ofter giving the printer a name it won't go to the next step...

Comment: In this case you can test-sign driver yourself or use already signed binaries. See update.

Comment: At the end I've self signed the drivers according to the [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520540/signed-ghostscript-postscript-print-driver/19585322#19585322] (link you gave me here) - it worked :)